# Spring boot - configuration doesn't load in junit test

Tags: spring, properties, spring-boot, load

I'm facing a weird issue in spring boot test case. I've tried everything which I could find but no luck. Can somebody help me.

When I run the spring boot app everything works fine. But test case doesn't load partnerConfig properties (It loads other properties but not partnerConfig).
 If you have any hint please ping me.

## Yaml file

```
config:
     MH:
         partner.id: "441"
         tiny.url.domain: "http://mh.local.upgrd.co/"
     EY:
         partner.id: "11"
         tiny.url.domain: "http://ey.local.upgrd.co/"
```

---

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class PartnerConfig {
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> config = new HashMap<>();
}
```

---

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MainMethodRunner.class})
public class PartnerConfigTestIT {
    @Autowired
    PartnerConfig partnerConfig;


    @Test
    public void should_get_carrierCode_from_partnerId() {
        //partnerConfig.config is not available in tests
    }
 }
```

---

When I run the spring boot app everything works fine. But test case doesn't load partnerConfig properties (It loads other properties but not partnerConfig).
If you have any hint please ping me.

Comment: What does `MainMethodRunner` look like?

Comment: @SpringBootApplication
public class MainMethodRunner { 

public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(MainMethodRunner.class, args);
    }}

Answer (score 0):

adding getter and setter for HashMap passed the test

Comment: Could please eloborate on your answere, so as to best help future users who might run into similar problems? It would be great if you could give some explanation and perhaps show some code!

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked for me finally:

**yaml file**

```
dynamodb:
    endpoint: https://localhost:4311
    accesskey: dummy
    secretkey: dummy

tinyurl:
     key.length: 12


partnerConfig:
     DH:
         partner.id: "056"
         tiny.url.domain: "dh.test.upgrd.co"
     HY:
         partner.id: "2001"
         tiny.url.domain: "hy.test.upgrd.co"
```

I wanted a class which dynamically maps parterConfig properties (without hardcoding keys with @Value) Because I wanted the capability where we should be able to add more partnerConfigs and it should not require code change.

**PartnerConfig class which maps properties to class**

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class PartnerConfig {

    private static final String TINY_URL_DOMAIN = "tiny.url.domain";
    private static final String PARTNER_ID = "partner.id";

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> partnerConfig = new HashMap<>();

    private BiMap<String, String> partnerIdToTinyUrlDomain = HashBiMap.create();

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        partnerConfig.forEach((carrierCode, partnerConf) ->
                partnerIdToTinyUrlDomain.put(partnerConf.get(PARTNER_ID), partnerConf.get(TINY_URL_DOMAIN)));
    }

    public String getPartnerId(String tinyUrlDomain) {
        if (isEmpty(tinyUrlDomain))
            throwTinyUrlNotFoundError(tinyUrlDomain);

        String partnerId = partnerIdToTinyUrlDomain.inverse().get(tinyUrlDomain);
        if (isEmpty(partnerId))
            throwTinyUrlNotFoundError(tinyUrlDomain);

        return partnerId;
    }

    public String getTinyUrlDomain(String partnerId) {
        if (isEmpty(partnerId))
            throwPartnerNotFoundError(partnerId);

        String tinyUrlDomain = partnerIdToTinyUrlDomain.get(partnerId);
        if (isEmpty(tinyUrlDomain))
            throwPartnerNotFoundError(partnerId);

        return tinyUrlDomain;
    }

    public void setPartnerConfig(Map<String, Map<String, String>> partnerConfig) {
        this.partnerConfig = partnerConfig;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getPartnerConfig() {
        return partnerConfig;
    }

    private String throwTinyUrlNotFoundError(String tinyUrlDomain) {
        String msg = String.format("tiny url mapping not found for domain %s", tinyUrlDomain);
        throw new TinyUrlNotFoundException(msg);
    }

    private String throwPartnerNotFoundError(String partnerId) {
        String msg = String.format("partner %s is not configured", partnerId);
        throw new PartnerConfigurationException(msg);
    }


}
```

**and Unit Test looked like**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MainMethodRunnerTest.class})
@IntegrationTest
public class PartnerConfigTestIT {
    @Autowired
    PartnerConfig partnerConfig;

    @Test
    public void getTinyUrlDomain_should_return_tinyUrlDomain_from_partnerId() {
        assertEquals("hy.test.upgrd.co", partnerConfig.getTinyUrlDomain("2001"));
    }


}
```

Comment: This is an Integration-Test, not a Unit-Test ;) You would not be able to load  the configuration data inside a Unit-Test. I assume your original problem should have hapenned in your production code as well? AFAIK `@ConfigurationProperties` will only work on visible fields, to you have either to provider `Getters/Setters` or make the fields `public`.